# When does std priority queue compare the values?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, priority-queue

I have a priority queue and the compare function references a value accessed by multiple threads. So it has to be protected by a mutex. Except I don't know when this compare function is ran. Is it ran when I push a value or when I pop a value? Example code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>


using namespace std;


int main()
{   
    int compare = 7;
    mutex compare_m;


    auto cmp = [&](int a, int b) {return abs(compare - a)>=abs(compare-b);};
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> x(cmp);
    mutex x_m;

    //in thread
    {   
        scoped_lock m1(x_m);
        //do I need this?
        scoped_lock m(compare_m);
        x.push(6);
    }

    //in thread
    {   
        scoped_lock m1(x_m);
        //do I need this?
        scoped_lock m(compare_m);
        x.pop();
    }

}
```

Comment: If the compare function is not run when pushing a value, then the values are stored unsorted. How long does it take to find an extreme element from an unsorted collection? What is the required time complexity for popping an element? Is it possible that the values are not sorted?

Comment: *"the compare function references a value accessed by multiple threads"* -- If the result of comparing two values can change over time (because other threads have changed the value of `compare`) then your priority queue is going to be unreliable unless the comparison is run only when popping, right? Otherwise your queue is based on stale data. This is a bigger concern than where the mutex would go, because in one case (comparing when pushing) a mutex would not be enough to maintain the integrity of your priority queue.

Comment: While implementing a container, I would expect a comparison function to remain a function (in the sense: for the same inputs it always gives the same result). Changing that invariant might lead to some very quirky bugs (e.g. when some part of `heapify` comparisons would have been omitted but should not have been or vice versa).
It looks like when `compare` changes the value, you might need to rebuild the whole priority queue, with a new comparison function unfortunately.

Comment: "I don't know when this compare function is ran. Is it ran when I push a value": yes. "... or when I pop a value?": also yes. To be more accurate, it isn't specified, but this is the usual behaviour of priority queues, i.e. those that are implemented as priority heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, if it is not documented anything can happen (and then we cannot then reason about when comparator is invoked).

If we take a look into cppreference, [push](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/push) is defined in terms of [push_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap), which then reorganizes the elements into a heap. Given it then needs to reorganize, we can reason that it invokes the comparator. A similar situation happens with `pop`, that invokes `pop_heap`, which again modifies the underlying heap. So again, invoking comparator.

So the above implies you need a critical section on both (however please notice the comments regarding whether it is actually *safe* to change the behaviour of comparison function while the pq contains elements).

Comment: *"if it is not documented anything can happen"* -- but there is documentation in this case. While there is not a requirement that any comparisons happen, there is an upper limit given on the first page you linked to: *"Logarithmic number of comparisons plus [other stuff]"*. So it's not the case that anything can happen, just anything that stays at or under a logarithmic number of comparisons. (There is a similar limitation for `pop`.)

Comment: Yeah, I should have expressed that better - "anything not otherwise limited by docs", like the O(logN) part. I was more concentrated on the lower bound, as in - can it be constantly `0`.

Comment: *"I should have [...]"* -- one reason the "Edit" link exists is to turn "should have"s into "done"s. ;)